# How can I install the ioncube loader in the DDEV-Local web container?

Tags: php, ioncube, ddev, oxid

I'm using DDEV to develop an OXID Esales Project. It's very comfortable to work with but now I have to install the Ioncube Loader. How can I do that? I have to put the .so file into the php direction inside the container and extend the php.ini. But I don't know how?
Can someone help me?

Project:
OXID E-Sales

- php7.1
- mysql5.7
- MacOS
- DDEV

Comment: Welcome @Florian - Since Ioncube seems to be a commercial product and supports only obsolete versions of PHP, you may not be able to find enough help here. But to add PHP configuration to DDEV-Local, follow the docs in [Providing custom PHP configuration](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-php-configuration-phpini).

Comment: Installing is trivial and although @rfay didn't spot it, Loaders for all current releases of PHP and older are available across a large number of platforms. There's an "install in under 60 seconds" video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp5ce9-LQKg that shows the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

[Note: This will never work on arm64 machines like the Mac M1, because ioncube provides only amd64/x86-64 binaries for their extension. If you need to bring something back to life from the past you can do it in the amd64 environment of [gitpod.io](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/gitpod/) for example.]

You could do this manually inside the web container each time you did a `ddev start`, but that doesn't sound like much fun.

Instead, we'll incorporate all the required changes into the add-on Dockerfile [see docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage).

Put these contents in your project's .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile and then it will (one time) build up your ddev-webserver image with the ioncube .so loader you need and the PHP configuration you need. This is for PHP 7.1 as you said, you'd change the PHP_VERSION for some other version.

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE

# Install the ioncube loader - set the PHP_VERSION to what you need
ENV PHP_VERSION=7.1
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && curl -sSlL  -o /tmp/ioncube.tar.gz https://downloads.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz && tar -x --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local/lib -f /tmp/ioncube.tar.gz ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so

# The ioncube_loader has to be the very first thing in the php.ini, so insert it there.
ENV PHP_INI_PATH=/etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/php.ini
RUN (echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so' && cat ${PHP_INI_PATH}) > ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new && mv ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new ${PHP_INI_PATH}
```

Comment: Wow :-) Thank you. It work. Exactly the solution I've searched for :)

Comment: Maybe u can help me again. For an older OXID shop I need to install the zendguardloader in the same way like above.

Comment: If you have a new question, please make a new question with full details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852763/ddev-integration-zendguard-loader

Comment: @rfay I changed PHP_VERSION to 7.4, but when checking with `ddev exec php --version` after starting the ddev project, it does not show ionCube. In the ddev logs I see this entry `Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so: /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hi @NickWeisser - The way to study the problem you're having is to `ddev ssh` and execute the instructions one at a time and see what happens. But reading https://www.ioncube.com/ suggests to me that ioncube doesn't run above php7.2, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I released a [ddev addon](https://github.com/oblakstudio/ddev-ioncube).

Will add ARM support asap :)

Answer (score 0):

- add new **.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile** and adjust the **PHP_VERSION** variable to the target PHP version:

```
    ENV PHP_VERSION=7.4
    
    RUN bash -c ' \
        ARCH=$(uname -m); \
        if [[ $ARCH == arm* || $ARCH == aarch64 ]]; then \
            IONCUBE_LIB="https://downloads.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_aarch64.tar.gz"; \
        else \
            IONCUBE_LIB="https://downloads.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz"; \
        fi; \
        mkdir -p /usr/local/lib; \
        curl -sSlL -o /tmp/ioncube.tar.gz $IONCUBE_LIB; \
        tar -x --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local/lib -f /tmp/ioncube.tar.gz ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so \
    '
    
    
    ENV PHP_INI_PATH=/etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/php.ini
    RUN (echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so' && cat ${PHP_INI_PATH}) > ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new && mv ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new ${PHP_INI_PATH}
    
    ENV PHP_INI_PATH=/etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/cli/php.ini
    RUN (echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so' && cat ${PHP_INI_PATH}) > ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new && mv ${PHP_INI_PATH}.new ${PHP_INI_PATH}
```