# DDEV Integration Zendguard Loader

Tags: php, docker, ddev, oxid

I'm using DDEV in an older OXID Esales Project (4.6). Now I have to install the [Zendguard Loader](https://www.zend.com/downloads/zend-guard-loader). How can I do that? I have to put the .so file into the php direction inside the container and extend the php.ini. I [asked earlier about the Ioncube loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390108/how-can-i-install-the-ioncube-loader-in-the-ddev-local-web-container) and that works fine with DDEV-Local. But I don't know how to integrate the zendguard loeader? Can someone help me?

Comment: you do it exactly the same way as you installed ioncube, just use zend guard files instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Zendguard Loader from their [website](https://www.zend.com/downloads/zend-guard-loader). (Linux, 64-bit, PHP5.6)
2. Place the tarball in your project's .ddev/web-build/ directory
3. Add this Dockerfile as .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
ADD zend-loader-php5.6-linux-x86_64_update1.tar.gz /etc/php/5.6
RUN echo "zend_extension=/etc/php/5.6/zend-loader-php5.6-linux-x86_64/ZendGuardLoader.so" >>/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/zendguardloader.ini
RUN phpenmod zendguardloader
```

4. `ddev start`.
5. `ddev exec php --version` will show you that it's active
6. Read the README.txt provided in the tarball and follow instructions as needed.